How to resend a document which is already out for signature
I am trying to determine whether Adobe Esign offers an option to resend a document that has already been sent out for signature.
I am attempting to resend the agreement below.
{
  "id": "CBJCHBCAABAAfZdBouQN0DXd6VCuQfJmeg7oVbSdQ4L0",
  "name": "[DEMO USE ONLY] Application Authorization Email",
  "groupId": "CBJCHBCAABAAiqBQw1jkRj3BzqrpM0kH_NeIeOcyk2JP",
  "type": "AGREEMENT",
  "message": "",
  "participantSetsInfo": [
    {
      "id": "CBJCHBCAABAAyn_k3dq7ij7_FCf1PjU8c936sJk_5NDo",
      "memberInfos": [
        {
          "email": "<--my email-->",
          "deliverableEmail": true,
          "id": "CBJCHBCAABAAMqb3r_hxCOrPYl_WF3jQqLLVMHv-EKol",
          "securityOption": {
            "authenticationMethod": "NONE"
          }
        }
      ],
      "role": "SIGNER",
      "order": 1
    }
  ],
  "senderEmail": "<--sender email-->",
  "createdDate": "2024-05-09T15:29:06Z",
  "lastEventDate": "2024-05-09T15:29:37Z",
  "signatureType": "ESIGN",
  "ccs": [
    {
      "email": "case.worker2@orhive.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "case.manager2@orhive.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "locale": "en_US",
  "status": "OUT_FOR_SIGNATURE",
  "documentVisibilityEnabled": false,
  "hasFormFieldData": false,
  "hasSignerIdentityReport": false,
  "agreementSettingsInfo": {
    "canEditFiles": true,
    "canEditElectronicSeals": true,
    "canEditAgreementSettings": true,
    "showAgreementReminderSentEvents": false,
    "hipaaEnabled": false,
    "showDocumentsViewedEvents": false
  },
  "sendType": "REGULAR_SEND",
  "senderSigns": "NEVER",
  "createdGroupId": "CBJCHBCAABAAiqBQw1jkRj3BzqrpM0kH_NeIeOcyk2JP",
  "documentRetentionApplied": false
}

I have attempted to use the following update API to modify and resend the agreement, but it consistently displays the validations below. I have tried with and without the parameters mentioned in the response message.
{
  "code": "MODIFYING_IMMUTABLE_FIELDS",
  "message": "Name cannot be modified, DocumentVisibilityEnabled can not be modified, SignatureType     cannot be modified, Locale cannot be modified, Message cannot be modified, Status cannot be modified, CCs cannot be modified, ParticipantSetsInfo cannot be modified, SendType cannot be modified"
}

I have used PUT agreements/{agreementId} to update and resent.
Playload I have tried are
1.
{
  "expirationTime": "2024-05-20T15:29:06Z"
}




{
  "fileInfos": [
    {
      "transientDocumentId":  "CBSCTBABDUAAABACAABAAVFIVH2gJGN8Ix0nr1-7igvQqkTKAiDEDwCQBTInpd2GMLiscBqQW_p1sxu2eRJRtD-5vrwH9QGFTjG5fKGuFce5ZEzriM-CAGpTtF1n21EaIWLpvH3zdvuWC927a4-3m5ADvmp7fHtNBZVj2MUn8JXmd_S1POYTGUI8GvryPevgGvpP-pagkv-Pm-ganDseh8i7Yw2kO8-kcV2lg7wBCoh4a0WiAATKG-touXU5nu6nUZ_2LZmaQLsWmdX38SfH57hWUdjt4vtl1qJ6tTq5bKzDnWh7BWJokYxOBrWmWzxzBkNWhAUHlpoaCJ6yXsJDOS62Acd7j-HUfPKPoEMEiA2aop2A2ZLQYBv63GjTxm4_KYorCd_l-07ixCRJcMIbF"
    }
  ],
  "name": "[DEMO USE ONLY] Application Authorization Email",
  "participantSetsInfo": [
    {
      "id": "CBJCHBCAABAAyn_k3dq7ij7_FCf1PjU8c936sJk_5NDo",
      "memberInfos": [
        {
          "email": "<<--email-->",
          "deliverableEmail": true,
          "id": "CBJCHBCAABAAMqb3r_hxCOrPYl_WF3jQqLLVMHv-EKol",
          "securityOption": {
            "authenticationMethod": "NONE"
          }
        }
      ],
      "role": "SIGNER",
      "order": 1
    }
  ],
  "signatureType": "ESIGN",
  "status": "OUT_FOR_SIGNATURE"
}

Is this resend functionality possible using Abode Esign?
If possible any rest api are available to achive it?
Is it possible to achive this functionality using developer account?
